# How to show label on top when circular image is changing in circular wheel?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am implementing circular animation .I am facing two issues .

- I want to scrolling anticlockwise (which is not working).It is working only clockwise.
  Explain more: I want to scroll images when user touch his finger circularly on browser we use touch mouse on device we use touchstart .But it is not working on anticlockwise direction.
- I want to change lable value (depend which image is on top).I take ("a","b"."c"...etc) images name so it show names which is on top ?

http://jsfiddle.net/naveennsit/sFcCU/6/

```
<lable>Title</lable>

<div id='container'>
    <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/66ip1iz8cm3wf2l/dial.png" style="position:absolute;top:=;left:;" id="dial1"></img>
    <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/siqq3e8kdaefqn8/icon_0.png" style="position:absolute;top:60px;left:190px;" id="dial2"></img>
    <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/zikxwpakha2ei1v/icon_1.png" style="position:absolute;top:100px;left:100px;" id="dial3"></img>
    <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/dn5n76r6yr1tzpd/icon_2.png" style="position:absolute;top:180px;left:70px;" id="dial4"></img>
    <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/vu9uckyoo7k8wcc/icon_3.png" style="position:absolute;top:270px;left:70px;" id="1"></img>
    <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/lnb9h4hazcd619u/icon_4.png" style="position:absolute;top:370px;left:110px;" id="dial5"></img>
    <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/pt0q3zbdxt3843d/icon_5.png" style="position:absolute;top:420px;left:230px;" id="dial6"></img>
    <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/j9ybktafm0v08ff/icon_6.png" style="position:absolute;top:350px;left:340px;" id="dial7"></img>
    <img src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/nuh0njoeczd94gm/icon_7.png" style="position:absolute;top:250px;left:390px;" id="dial8"></img>
    <div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is a syntax error.

Arrays are defined with `[]` and not  `{}` so you need to change it to

```
var arry =["a","b","c","d","e","f","g" ,"h"];
```

To invert the rotation increase the `currentAngle` instead of decreasing it..

```
boxes[idx].currentAngle++;
```

To check which one is the *top* one just check their angle (*90 degrees is the top*)

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/sFcCU/8/